# Datatable column filter asp net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-datatables

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o plugin do datatables column filter, o mesmo não me reporta erro mas também não gera os filtros, segue meu código:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $('#myTable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });

            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
                "language": {
                    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ".",
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sNext": "Próximo",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                        "sLast": "Último"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                    }
                }, scrollY: 2, scrollX: 300, searching: true, retrieve: true, ordering: false, rowReorder: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

minha tabela:

```
 @using (@Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "AcompanhamentoEntrega", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div id="tabelaFenix">
                    <table id="myTable" class="stripe table compact hover" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead style="position:static">
                            <tr>
                                <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">DATA EXPEDIÇÃO</th>
                                <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">STATUS ENTREGA</th>
                                <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">DATA ENTREGA</th>
                                <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">CONFIRMACAO</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listaEntrega.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].data_expedicao, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "4px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" })</td>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].status_entrega, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "4px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" })</td>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].data_entrega, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "10px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" }) </td>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].confirmacao, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "18px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" }) </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            }
```

Meus imports:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Link do datatables: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
```

Comment: Gerar os filtros, que você diz, é relativo às colunas que não aparecem as opções de filtragem, certo?

Comment: isso mesmo, este filtro deveria gerar um filtro por coluna, mas ele não esta gerando, e nem me devolve um erro por debug

Comment: Já tentou inspecionar a página pra ver se não houve algum erro com o Datatables?

Comment: Sim, o unico erro que deu é por eu ter tentado iniciar duas vezes, porém tirei a função que traduz e não devolve nenhum tipo de erro.

Comment: No seu lugar, eu voltaria um pouco atrás nos tutoriais do Datatables e colocaria o filtro mais simples possível.

Comment: eu estou no momento utilizando o filtro global, porém ele não é totalmente preciso, no caso de eu precisar filtrar dois campos de data, o filtro não será preciso entendeu? não sei se é alguma incompatibilidade com mvc5

Comment: Acho que não é isso não. MVC é uma coisa, e o Datatables outra. Você tem um link de onde você começou a fazer essa alteração? Talvez seja só algum ajuste.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27192/discussion-between-jeff-silva-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, o [dataTables](https://www.datatables.net) possui um filtro global, onde ele filtra os dados de todos os elementos da tabela. 
Pela sua pergunta você está querendo um filtro em cada coluna. Para isso, basta modificar a fim de adicionar um `input` em cada `header`, para realizar a busca, Ficaria assim o seu código:

```
    // Setup - Adicioona o input no header da tabela
$('#myTable thead tr#filterrow th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#myTable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" onclick="stopPropagation(event);" placeholder="Busca em '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

// Aplica o filtro nas colunas
$("#myTable thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
    table
        .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );

  function stopPropagation(evt) {
    if (evt.stopPropagation !== undefined) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

Você pode ver um exemplo funcional no [JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/575qtzru/2/)

Resposta retirada com base no [forum do dataTables.](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/20272/how-to-put-individual-column-filter-inputs-at-top-of-columns)

Comment: Os filtros ainda não aparecem, apesar da página em si não devolver nenhum erro no navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Meio atrasado (só 4 anos), mas estou respondendo para server de referência para quem teve este problema.

O autor da pergunta está tentando executar a função no elemento footer da tabela sendo que o mesmo não existe.

Além disso, o código também requer o id correto no Js.

O código abaixo deve funcionar no Razor:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabelaFenix').DataTable({
                "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
                "language": {
                    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ".",
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sNext": "Próximo",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                        "sLast": "Último"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                    }
                }, scrollY: 2, scrollX: 300, searching: true, retrieve: true, ordering: false, rowReorder: true
            });
            
            $('#tabelaFenix tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $('#myTable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });

            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });
            });
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "AcompanhamentoEntrega", FormMethod.Post)) {
<div id="tabelaFenix">
  <table id="myTable" class="stripe table compact hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead style="position:static">
      <tr>
        <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">DATA EXPEDIÇÃO</th>
        <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">STATUS ENTREGA</th>
        <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">DATA ENTREGA</th>
        <th align="left" style="font-size:10px">CONFIRMACAO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @for (int i = 0; i
      < Model.listaEntrega.Count(); i++) { <tr>
        <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].data_expedicao, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "4px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" })</td>
        <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].status_entrega, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "4px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" })</td>
        <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].data_entrega, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "10px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" }) </td>
        <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaEntrega[i].confirmacao, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "18px", @class = "form-controldata_expedicao" }) </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>DATA EXPEDIÇÃO</th>
        <th>STATUS ENTREGA</th>
        <th>DATA ENTREGA</th>
        <th>CONFIRMACAO</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
}
```